# How can I remove a list of pairs from the whole segment?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given that I've got a interval from `[A, B]` (where `A, B` are integers) and a list of non-overlapping intervals of `(C_i, D_i), i = 1..N` (it's guaranteed that `[A, B]` contains `(C_i, D_i), i = 1..N`), the goal is to *subtract* `(C_i, D_i), i = 1..N` from `[A, B]`:

```
A, B = 1, 10
intervals = [2, 3], [5, 6]
...
result = [[1, 1], [4, 4], [7, 10]]
```

Is there a built in function for that in `numpy` or I have to do in a brute force way?

Comment: If `C` and `D` are overlapping, how come the result contains `[4,4]` ?

Comment: Fixed the description.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing for that in numpy, but you do not have to use brute force. As the (C_i, D_i) intervals are non overlapping, they can be sorted, and once sorted, you can just iterate over them:

```
def remove_intervals(A, B, intervals):
    cur = A
    result = []
    for C, D in sorted(intervals):
        if cur < C:
            result.append([cur, C-1])
        cur = D+1
    if D < B:
        result.append([cur, B])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [python-intervals](https://pypi.org/project/python-intervals/) package.